# Придаточное меры и степени?

Tags: синтаксис

Проверьте пожалуйста, правильно ли определила

На службе он управлялся так хорошо, *что его без труда удалось сделать вторым человеком после шефа*.

Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, это придаточное меры и степени. Всё верно.

Answer (score 2):

Здесь **двойное значение: степени и следствия.**

Сравните:

а) Значение **степени**: На улице **так холодно**, **как** бывает только зимой.

Б) Значение **степени и следствия**: Тучи шли **так низко, что** задевали верхушки деревьев.